# Curiosity about "conditional trig identities"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ho.history-overview, plane-geometry, trigonometric-functions

Perhaps this should be cross-posted on Math Stackexchange, but it came up in the context of some research mathematics (quaternion orders, etc.)  In this context, I have three angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ of a triangle, and three cosines $a = \cos(\alpha)$ and $b = \cos(\beta)$ and $c = \cos(\gamma)$.  Out of some magic popped the following quantity:
$$D = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2 abc - 1.$$
Well, ok, it's not magic, it's related to the discriminant of something.  But who doesn't like such a cubic equation?

Lo and behold, [wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Further_%22conditional%22_identities_for_the_case_%CE%B1_+_%CE%B2_+_%CE%B3_=_180%C2%B0) there's a family of "conditional trig identities," among which one finds
$$\cos^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\beta) + \cos^2(\gamma) = 1 - 2 \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) \cos(\gamma),$$
**IF** $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 180^\circ$.  In other words, the identity above is conditional on the angles being those of a Euclidean triangle.

Now my questions...

1. What's the history of this identity?  There's no references in this section of Wikipedia, and just a few odd youtube videos because such identities are useful for contest problems.  Does it have a nice name?  It's not *too* far from some ratio-sum identities of Euler ([E749 at the Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E749.pdf)), but it doesn't match them either.
2. Does this identity have a known interpretation in terms of curvature, comparison triangles, etc.?  I mean $D = 0$ occurs if the triangle is Euclidean. I suspect this is an "if and only if" and can check whether $D < 0$ and $D > 0$ correspond to hyperbolic/spherical triangles.  But does $D$ match something that metric geometry people know?
3. Does this identity have a direct geometric proof?  I've seen proofs of related identities, and one can just hack it out.  But is there something *nice* going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Can't you change this "conditional trig identity" to an "unconditional" identity for any two angles $\alpha,\beta$ by setting $\gamma = 180^{\circ} - \alpha - \beta$.

Comment: Yep... that's just what Wikipedia (and others?) call these identities.  Maybe if someone understands the geometry underlying these identities, they can suggest a better name!

Comment: I'd have to digest it a bit more but the discussion around Theorem 4.2 in this [paper](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/bilu/bilu.pdf) seems relevant.  For instance the determinant of equation (4.2) seems to be exactly your identity.

Comment: Woah!  And for the exact same reasons too... Thanks for pointing me towards that paper!  It doesn't answer the question, but it shows that I'm in good company looking at these things.  :)

Comment: Name of the paper @RBega2 [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1210790): [McMullen - Galois orbits in the moduli space of all triangles](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/bilu/bilu.pdf).

Comment: There is some discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670286/if-abc-0-then-prove-that-the-value-of-the-determinant-is-0?

Comment: Similar equations show up at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044329/an-inequality-related-to-the-cosine-theorem